# Chart from multiple lists in SharePoint 2010

Tags: chart-web-part

I have a project to create a chart from multiple lists on SharePoint. But I'm not sure what is the best way to approach this requirement. We have a warehouse and shops in few cities. We've got one list containing the data of all the items that we store in the warehouse, the data is organized by product, quantity , date of purchase and date of delivery. We also have other lists of the shops (one list for each shop) containing the information of the salesmen and their personal achievement for each month(quantity items sales per day). What my boss wants is a chart that will show him each salesman's personal achievement from all the shops on monthly basis, and what percentage from the total quantity of items in the warehouse has s/he sold.

Any idea how shall I approach this requirement?

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Luka, we need to know some more details here. 1. Are these lists in the same site? 2. What technologies do you feel comfortable working with to build the charts?

Comment: Robert, thank you for taking the time and reading my question! The lists are on different sites, every shop has its own SharePoint site and the warehouse is on a different site as well. So far I've used only the default web part provided by Microsoft and I've also embedded few excel charts. I would like a suggestion with some of those two web parts that I am familiar with, but as this project is way more complicated than all I have done so far, I’m open to alternatives if there’s no solution.

Answer (score 0):

Given your current skill set, you are going to have a strong learning curve if you do this strictly using SharePoint.

If you want to make your life easier, you might want to try and convince your company to invest in the [LightningTools](http://lightningtools.com/) Chart and Cross-Site Collection web parts ([here is a video demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TntwRm78b_4)). I'm not affiliated and I've only tested them out and I'm not even completely sure that it would support a "mashup" style of app so my final option might be the best over all.

You can also find a way to use something like the [Data View web part](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Display-data-from-multiple-sources-in-a-single-Data-View-f9898d20-a5ab-4973-9d16-9f4e4c088ae1?ui=en-US&rs=en-ZA&ad=ZA&fromAR=1), to join the lists together.

But there is also the option of using [Excel and PowerPivot to build a mashup of the sites](http://blogs.c5insight.com/Home/entryid/438/Use-Power-Pivot-to-Merge-Related-SharePoint-List-Data). If you have the PowerPivot features of SharePoint installed, that might be your best choice. Even if you don't, you might still be able to use Excel Services to embed your charts and tables. Plus, PowerPivot/Excel is just easier to understand, IMO. If I had to do this and do it quickly, this is the road I would take.

Here are the high-level steps. I'm leaving a lot of details out as I am not familiar with your specific scenario.

1. Open the warehouse list in Excel - from the *List* tab in SharePoint click the export to Excel button. Personally, I'd change the name of the *Table* so that you can identify it more easily.
2. Repeat the step above for all the lists but importing each of them into *new Worksheets* in the same *Workbook*.
3. Use PowerPivot to build your data model by connecting the tables using the fields that relate each list in a way that you can get the data you need.
4. Build your pivot table and add any charts you might want.
5. If possible, embed the dashboard into SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this approach can be useful (because I'm not sure if it will work with lists from different sites), but I propose using Javascript code.
You can check my question on [Make a Chart with multiple Sharepoint lists](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/255197/70877).
For this you'll need [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) and [Angular-chart](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/).